# Syncing an iTunes smart playlist to an iPod Video when specifying another Library

Tags: itunes, ipod

I've created a smart playlist under iTunes (for video podcasts) I've done this for another library (I hold down the shift key when starting iTunes to specify the library).

When I sync the iPod Video, the playlist does not get copied over. I have tried both automatic sync and manual sync. Under manual sync, I've tried to drag the playlist over, without success.

Is this behavior due to using an alternate library? I have had no such problems in the past when I have used the main library.

I am using Windows XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just discovered (through a search on iLounge)  that my "copying playlist" problem has nothing to do with libraries and everything to do with iTunes 9.

From the response of JBridges to [this thread](http://forums.ilounge.com/showthread.php?t=250664) comes the following:

> On the Podcast tab:
>
> 1. Leave 'Sync Podcasts: checked
> 2. UNCHECK 'Automatically include...'
> 3. Check the appropriate playlists in 'Include Episodes from Playlists'

I've tried this suggestion with audio podcasts on my iPod Touch with success.